# How can I work with large DEM in GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem

I have a very large DEM (about 115Gb). I cannot work with it on my computer. I need to clip a river catchment from this DEM. I work in GIS. How can I do this?

Comment: why can't you work with it on your computer?  What happens?  Do you get error messages?  What steps are you following?

Comment: Set environment Extent to polygon, snap raster and cell size to dem. Use raster calculator "dem". This will give you manageable extract

Comment: ArcMap cannot upload the DEM. It is too large. It has 115GB.

Answer (score 3):

From the IDLE interface that comes in the python folder of ArcGIS, you can execute any tool without actually loading the layer into the GUI.  Go to IDLE's File Menu, New File, and type something like:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.Clip_management("c:/your_path/your_raster.tif","","c:/your_path/catchment_clip.tif", "c:/your_path/your_catchment.shp", "#", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Read details on the arguments in the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm).  You might need to fill in extent coordinates.
Run it from the Run Menu in IDLE, saving it with the extension .py.  Then, if it succeeds, you can load the smaller catchment_clip.tif into ArcMap to see how it came out.

Comment: In fact, I have the 5 m contour. First I have to cut the area of interest, then I have to create the tin and the raster.

Comment: Once it's clipped, is it small enough to open in ArcMap?  It's not too hard to find the arcpy functions to create a TIN or raster if not.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need to load the layer into the GUI first. In ArcMap and QGIS it works similar.

Just run the tool from the toolbox. This way you don't need any python code. For ArcMap use the raster clip tool. I think in Qgis it is called "clip raster by mask layer".

If all else fails you can revert to ogr2ogr to handle the clipping for you.